# Text on a background image within a container

Tags: html, css, image

I want a responsive img with text on top. Ive tried several different ways and I semi-get there with a bunch of kinks when I try to make it responsive, so I appreciate if anyone has a simple solution.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/born2code1983/efgt0r0f/1/)**

**Code snippet demonstration :**

```css
.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://phillipbrande.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/random-pic-14.jpg?w=620" class="img-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean this? https://jsfiddle.net/svqtk4rz/

Comment: Yes, thanks. Will I have to use media queries for the text to be responsive as well?

Comment: Posted the solution for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `font-size: calc(2vw + 2vh + 2vmin)` (tweak around the values to your need) to make text responsive with respect to viewport size :)

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: calc(2vw + 2vh + 2vmin);
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://phillipbrande.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/random-pic-14.jpg?w=620" class="img-fluid">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can try this , here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Text within container</h2>

<div class="container">
  <img src="abc.jpg" alt="abc" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Works perfectly as well thanks. I cant seem to find a class to make the text responsive. Is there one or do I have to use media queries to make responsive text in bootstrap?

Comment: You can try using media queries.It will give definitely give you output

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `position` to `absolute` or `fixed`

```
.img-fluid{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    opacity:0.4;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for an image use the concept:

```
{
    display: table; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
}
```

for text to display on image use the concept

```
{
    display: table-cell;
    verticl-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and adjust the text on image giving top or bottom or left or right}
use the class `img-responsive` to not to change the width and height of image in all the views.

Comment: Change `verticl-align` to `vertical-align` and set `img` or `img p` before the `{`.

Comment: Mark the answer which solved your query as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML:

<div class="banner">
<img src="images/star.png" class="img-responsive" width="150" height="150" alt="star">
<h2>This is a Star</h2>
</div>

CSS:

.banner img{position:relative; width:100%; height:auto;}
 .banner h2{[psition:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; font-size:30px;
 line-height:30px;}
```